# HOw can i use subdomain with django and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I have my main site at  www.example.com

I want to run sites like site1.example.com

I tried this

```
<VirtualHost ip:80>
DocumentRoot /home/user/django/app
ServerAlias site1.example.com
```

I have also added record to /etc/hosts but its not working.

i am able to ping site1.example.com from server but not from outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i am able to ping site1.example.com from server but not from outside

This is not a Django problem. `ping` is a low-level IP protocol (ICMP) that is handled well down from the HTTP server (application) level.

Adding something to `/etc/hosts` only affects the machine that `/etc/hosts` is on.

You should get subdomains working with static web pages (e.g. "Hello World") first, leaving Django out of it. Then read up on `django.contrib.sites` and go from there.